# display Jframe above another Jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe

when I call a JFrame from another JFrame by creating an object it gets display under it so I have to minimize the first one in order to see the second one. Does anyone know how can I get the second JFrame on the first JFrame? 
thx a lot!!

Comment: Generally a Swing application should only have a single JFrame. Use a JDialog for a child window. Make sure you specify the frame as the parent of the dialog and the dialog will be displayed on top of the from If you have a problem then post your [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) Note that if the 2nd window is a modal `JDialog` which specifies the `JFrame` as the parent component, it should appear on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `frame2.setVisible(true);`.

The method `setVisible()` will show you the frame you used it on, on top of all the other frames you have.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
frame.setAlwaysOnTop( true );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
frame2.setVisible(true); //makes frame visible
```

but add when you initialize your second frame following:

```
frame2.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```